# How do I Clear the Windows Mail Autodiscover Cache?

Tags: outlook, autodiscovery, autodiscover

I am debugging a custom Autodiscover implementation that works fine with MS Outlook and also passes the MS Remote Connectivity Analyzer.

However, I am having trouble with Windows Mail. I attempted to setup an account at a domain that didn't have the correct DNS records yet, and while the web server logs initially showed some remote requests from Microsoft servers to learn the Autodiscover settings, it apparently has decided to remember the protocol failure and never try again. This was days ago, and even now when I try to setup the account again I have found absolutely no Autodiscover activity in the logs. In contrast, MS Outlook and the Outlook iOS/Android app request the settings (also originating from a MS server, not the device) every time an account is being setup.

How can I get Windows Mail (or Microsoft's provisioning service?) to retry Autodiscover like other clients do?

Answer (score 2):

Toclear the Logs is just like this:

In the from folder %localappdata%\Microsoft\Outlook\ you will find files "numbers_ Autodiscover.xml"

Delete all those files and restart Outlook

Source: https://gothamweb.com/esupport/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/254/0/clearing-autodiscover-cache-in-outlook

Comment: Thanks, but I already looked there. Windows Mail is not making any entries in the Outlook folder.

Comment: admins might set it here: ```HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook\AutoDiscover
source: https://www.howto-outlook.com/howto/autodiscoverconfiguration.htm